# Force bibtex to typeset doi in uppercase

Tags: bibtex, formatting, doi

My question is roughly dual to [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/508976). How do I force `bibtex` to format the word “DOI” below in uppercase?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents*}{bib.bib}
@article{milner92,
 author = {Robin Milner and Joachim Parrow and David Walker},
 title = {A Calculus of Mobile Processes, {I} and {II}},
 journal = {Inf. Comput.},
 volume = {100},
 number = {1},
 pages = {1--77},
 year = {1992},
 doi = {10.1016/0890-5401(92)90009-5},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\cite{milner92}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{bib.bib}

\end{document}
```

The `DeclareFieldFormat` solution mentioned in the [earlier question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/508976) doesn't seem relevant here (presumably it's specific to `biblatex`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents*}{bib.bib}
@article{milner92,
 author = {Robin Milner and Joachim Parrow and David Walker},
 title = {A Calculus of Mobile Processes, {I} and {II}},
 journal = {Inf. Comput.},
 volume = {100},
 number = {1},
 pages = {1--77},
 year = {1992},
 doi = {10.1016/0890-5401(92)90009-5},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\expandafter\ifcsname urlstyle\endcsname
  \providecommand{\doi}{DOI: \begingroup \urlstyle{rm}\Url}\else
  \providecommand{\doi}[1]{DOI: #1}%
  \fi

\begin{document}
\cite{milner92}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{bib}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Works for me - I’ll see what other answers materialise before accepting, in case there’s a simpler one. Thanks.

Comment: I accepted this initially but I’m afraid I had to change my mind - it doesn’t seem to work with the `doi` package (which I also need to turn my DOIs into hyperlinks). Back-patched my question accordingly.

Comment: If you have a new question ask a new question. Making answers invalid by adding new info to a question is not nice.

Comment: Fair enough. I’ll undo my change to this question and ask a new one.

Answer (score 1):

`plainnat` uses the macro `\doi` to typeset the DOI. If the macro is not defined, it will use the following replacement definitions

```
\providecommand{\url}[1]{\texttt{#1}}
\expandafter\ifx\csname urlstyle\endcsname\relax
  \providecommand{\doi}[1]{doi: #1}\else
  \providecommand{\doi}{doi: \begingroup \urlstyle{rm}\Url}\fi
```

Assuming you load `url` or `hyperref`, you could take that branch of the definition and go for

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{natbib}

\usepackage{url}
\newcommand{\doi}{\textsc{doi}: \begingroup \urlstyle{rm}\Url}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{milner92,
 author  = {Robin Milner and Joachim Parrow and David Walker},
 title   = {A Calculus of Mobile Processes, {I} and {II}},
 journal = {Inf. Comput.},
 volume  = {100},
 number  = {1},
 pages   = {1--77},
 year    = {1992},
 doi     = {10.1016/0890-5401(92)90009-5},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\cite{milner92}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image: Robin Milner, Joachim Parrow, and David Walker. A calculus of mobile processes, I and II. Inf. Comput., 100(1):1–77, 1992. DOI: 10.1016/0890-5401(92)90009-5.]

I used small caps instead of ALL CAPS, but of course that can easily be changed.

Comment: Thanks - I happen to be using `url` but I think I prefer the solution without the dependency. How do I switch to all caps?

Comment: @Roly Write `DOI` instead of `\textsc{doi}`.

Comment: Thanks. Accepted this in the end because it works with the `doi` package too, which I would also like to use. Means using `\renewcommand` rather than `\newcommand` for `\doi`.

Comment: Oops, I messed up there - actually it doesn’t work with the `doi` package. (I guess redefining `\doi` isn’t a good idea - my bad.) Any idea how to make this work with `doi`?