# Force bibtex to typeset doi in uppercase, when using doi package

Tags: bibtex, formatting, doi

A variant of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/518981) that adds the additional requirement that the solution work with the `doi` package.

How do I force bibtex to format the word “DOI” below in uppercase?

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{doi} % hyperlink URLs

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{milner92,
 author  = {Robin Milner and Joachim Parrow and David Walker},
 title   = {A Calculus of Mobile Processes, {I} and {II}},
 journal = {Inf. Comput.},
 volume  = {100},
 number  = {1},
 pages   = {1--77},
 year    = {1992},
 doi     = {10.1016/0890-5401(92)90009-5},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\cite{milner92}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the documentation says:

> The format of the doi can be controlled by
>   redefining the \doitext command,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{doi} % hyperlink URLs
\renewcommand{\doitext}{DOI:~}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{milner92,
 author  = {Robin Milner and Joachim Parrow and David Walker},
 title   = {A Calculus of Mobile Processes, {I} and {II}},
 journal = {Inf. Comput.},
 volume  = {100},
 number  = {1},
 pages   = {1--77},
 year    = {1992},
 doi     = {10.1016/0890-5401(92)90009-5},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\cite{milner92}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Looks good, thanks.